# Another Python NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python

I am having issues with a defined name error message in Python. I know there are quite a few responses to this question, but I cannot seem to find one that fits my situation. My code is as follows:

```
    #Gets the input of the property value from the user and calculates the individual and total revenue
    def main():
        class_A_input = int(input('Please enter the number of Class A seats sold: '))
        class_B_input = int(input('Please enter the number of Class B seats sold: '))
        class_C_input = int(input('Please enter the number of Class C seats sold: '))

    #Declares the cost for each class of ticket
        class_A_cost = 20
        class_B_cost = 15
        class_C_cost = 10

    #Passes the variable for each ticket class
        class_A(class_A_input, class_A_cost)
        class_B(class_B_input, class_B_cost)
        class_C(class_C_input, class_C_cost)

    #Calculates the total revenue
    total_revenue = (class_A_input * class_A_cost) + ,\
(class_B_input * class_B_cost) + (class_C_input * class_C_cost)
    print ('Total tickets revenue is $',format(total_revenue,',d'),sep='')

    #Calculates the class A revenue
    def class_A(A_input, A_cost):
        class_A_revenue = A_input * A_cost
        print ('The amount of Class A revenue is $',format(class_A_revenue,',d'),sep='')

    #Repeat definitions for Class B and Class C

    main()
```

I am running Python 3.6.0 and I am getting the following name error:

```
     total_revenue = (class_A_input * class_A_cost) + ,\
(class_B_input * class_B_cost) + (class_C_input * class_C_cost)
    NameError: name 'class_A_input' is not defined
```

I don't think I am declaring the variable before I use it. I have tried a variety of different solutions with no success. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check indentation or fix it here

Comment: Using comments that don't have the same level of indentation as the code they occur in is a good way to get yourself confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an indentation issue. `total_revenue` is global and trying to use local variable from `main()` in its calculation.

p.s. You should learn about functions in order to help you reduce duplication in your code.

Comment: There's no need to answer typo questions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Good point, but with significant white space, it isn't always clear if something is *just* a typo or if it is indicative of a fundamental misunderstanding on OP's part.